# Pub/sub in web2py? When user joins (database insert) how do I get notified immediately?

Tags: web2py, publish-subscribe

Creating a web2py app in which users log in by scanning a UPC-equipped card or sign up as new customers and when those things happen, I'd like to be informed immediately.

For example, a customer scans in and we find she needs to update her membership because it's near expiration, so that notification would appear in the admin console in real time.

What is the best way to do obtain instant notifications in web2py when a database record is inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database insert is handled via a particular controller action, just add some code to the controller to send the email notification. If the inserts can happen via multiple different avenues, you can instead use an [`_after_insert` callback](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#before-and-after-callbacks) in the model definition.

To send the email message asynchronously, you can use the built-in [scheduler](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#web2py-Scheduler) to queue the email to be sent by a worker process.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, but I should clarify. I'm not looking for an email notification. I'm imagining a Meteor-style pub/sub but with the much more robust feature set of web2py: the membership card is attached to an iPad (computer A). Scanning it inserts a "customer is in" record.  Then Ajax-drawn notification would appear instantly while admins are using computers B and C, all in different rooms.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, but I should clarify. I'm not looking for an email notification. 

I'm imagining a Meteor-style pub/sub but with the much more robust feature set of web2py: QR code scanner is attached to an iPad (computer A). Scanning it inserts a "customer is in" record.  Then Ajax-drawn notification would appear on admin screens instantly while admins are using computers B and C, all in different rooms from the one with the scanner.

Later the customer scans out, triggering a "customer is gone" record insert. Machines B and C are subscribers. They get notified that the customer has left.

Comment: AARGH! SO's fraud control got me confused. I apparently tried to spend too much time editing the comment or something. I wanted to formulate a precise answer but got booted out, and somehow managed to end up creating a new one. Please disregard the first comment.

Comment: Rereading [Anthony's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/440323/anthony) note 3 YEARS TOO LATE I realized he gave me exactly the answer I needed. Still applies too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like the solution I'm looking for is tornado+comet_messaging, [here on Github][1].

[1] https://github.com/abhayashenoy/pycon-apac/blob/master/web2py/gluon/contrib/comet_messaging.py